# Is there any recourse for a closed question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

Can I request to get a second opinion from another moderator or a vote from trusted members if [my question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/116945/9431) deserved to be put on hold? I believe I asked a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can, and here's how. Edit the question to improve it, and it will automatically go to [a list of questions](//judaism.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) that [those with enough reputation points](//judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can review for reopening if they think it now should be open. If you think it was perfectly fine as it was, you can raise the issue in a new question here on Meta, or in [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam) if you prefer. If it was closed by only a moderator, [pinging that moderator in a comment on the question (using @username)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/161792) will work, and you can use that to ask the moderator for clarification in case the closure explanation he posted is unclear.

Comment: I think you can ping any close voter, not just a moderator.